# Статистика по объему занимаемой директориями памяти за определенное время

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть каталог в котором очень много подкаталогов. Мне нужно получить иформацию о том какие файлы создавались в этом каталоге за определенное время и их размер. Нужную опцию в утилите `du` не нашел...

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что хочется команду вида `zzz --from 10-01-2000 --to 12-12-2010 /tmp` и она распечатает суммарный размер всех файлов в каталоге, которые попадают в заданный диапазон дат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**предуведомление**:

под «узнать их размер», насколько я понял, вы подразумевали «узнать, сколько **всего** они занимают места». на это я и ответил ниже. если же интересует размер каждого файла по отдельности, просто уберите последнюю часть предлагаемого конвейера (`tail` или `grep`). да и опцию `-c` у программы `du`, если общий итог тоже не нужен.

---

можно воспользоваться возможностью программы `du` выдавать (в том числе) общий итог при указании опции `-c` (итог идёт последней строкой, которую можно получить, например, командой `tail -n 1`). а список нужных файлов получать программой `find` с соответствующими опциями:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +10 -ctime -20 | xargs du -c | tail -n 1
```

пояснения для опций `find`:

- `-type f` — искать только файлы
- `-ctime +10` — созданные (точнее, изменялся их статус) более 10 суток назад
- `-ctime -20` — созданные (точнее, изменялся их статус) менее 20 суток назад

т.е. будут найдены файлы, созданные в промежутке 10-20 суток назад.

---

если предполагается, что в именах файлов (и путях к ним) могут встретиться спецсимволы типа пробела, стоит воспользоваться опцией `-print0` — тогда `find` будет разделять результаты не символом `\n`, а нулевым символом с кодом `0x0`. программе `xargs` об этом тоже нужно сообщить — опцией `-0`:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +10 -ctime -20 -print0 | xargs -0 du -c | tail -n 1
```

---

если количество (или общая длина) аргументов, переданных программе `xargs`, превысит установленные в системе лимиты (узнать их можно так: `$ cat /dev/null | xargs --show-limits`), то `xargs` разобьёт их на отдельные «порции» и запустит `du -c` для каждой «порции» отдельно. т.е., в вывод могут попасть несколько строк с общим итогом. тогда стоит конечную часть конвейера (`tail -n 1`) заменить, например, вызовом программы `grep`, указав ей отбирать строки, заканчивающиеся строкой `total`:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +10 -ctime -20 -print0 | xargs -0 du -c | grep -P '\ttotal$'
```