# Удаление файлов за большой промежуток времени

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Этот вопрос по сути является продолжением [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594746/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) вопроса. У меня есть каталог с большим числом подкаталогов. Как я могу удалить часть файлов в этих каталогах, которые хранятся там более определенного времени и с определенным шаблоном в имени. Например, удаление всех файлов старше 3 месяцев, название которых начинается со 'start' оканчивается так: `end.zip`.

Comment: `find <нужные параметры> | xargs rm`. А параметры можно узнать из `man find`.

Comment: | xargs rm - необязательно. find сам умеет вызывать (http://majestio.info/viewtopic.php?id=55)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, `| xargs rm` — абсолютно лишняя сущность. при наличии-то «живой» [опции `-delete`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.B9).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а, не знал. Тогда ещё проще )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> удаление всех файлов старше 3 месяцев, название которых начинается со `start` оканчивается так: `end.zip`

это можно осуществить программой `find`:

1. > удаление

   для этого служит опция `-delete`. сначала имеет смысл запустить без неё, чтобы проанализировать список найденных файлов.
2. > всех файлов

   для этого служит опция `-type f`.
3. > старше 3 месяцев

   смотря что значит «старше». если имеется в виду время модификации статуса файла, то подойдёт опция `-ctime +количество_суток`, если время модификации содержимого файла, то подойдёт опция `-mtime +количество_суток` ([а собственно время создания практически ни в каких файловых системах не сохраняется, так как это не требуется стандартом posix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67895/110559)).
4. > название которых начинается со `start` оканчивается так: `end.zip`

   для этого служит опция `-name маска`. что-то вроде `-name start\*end.zip` или `-name 'start*end.zip'`.

---

**итого**. посмотреть список:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +90 -name start\*end.zip
```

удалить:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +90 -name start\*end.zip -delete
```

Comment: А если задачу немного усложнить. Строка, которая состоит из `start` и `end.zip` находится не в названии файла, а в его содержании ?

Comment: это будет не «усложнить», а «задать совсем другой вопрос».

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595234/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC