# Удаление файлов за большой промежуток времени с определенным содержимым

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Этот вопрос по сути является продолжением [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595201/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8/595212?noredirect=1#comment802428_595212) вопроса. У меня есть каталог с большим числом подкаталогов. Как я могу удалить часть файлов в этих каталогах, которые хранятся там более определенного времени и с определенным шаблоном в содержимом файла. Например, удаление всех файлов старше 3 месяцев, которые содержат строку (или подстроку) с началом `start` и окончанием `end.zip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

этот ответ по сути является продолжением [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595212/178576) ответа.

только ввиду того, что программа `find` «не умеет» просматривать содержимое файлов, требуется дополнение, например, в виде программы `grep`:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +90 | xargs grep -l 'start.*end\.zip'
```

этой командой будет получен список файлов, время модификации статуса которых больше 90 суток, ничем не сжатых, содержащих требуемую последовательность символов (в одной строке).

опция `-l` программы `grep` служит для вывода только имён файлов, в которых найдено совпадение с указанным регулярным выражением.

---

если «всё окей», то этот список можно отправить по конвейеру программе `rm`:

```
$ find /путь -type f -ctime +90 | xargs grep -l 'start.*end\.zip' | xargs rm
```

Comment: Да, но Ваш прошлый ответ является по сути продолжением этого ответа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594746/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F/594782#594782

Comment: @faoxis, в принципе, любой конвейер, в котором используются `find` и `xargs` (а это весьма удобная в очень многих случаях «парочка») можно считать «продолжением» одной и той же истории.

Comment: А можно ли с помощью это связки найти упоминание о них на `stackoverflow` ?

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос, я понял. :)

Comment: @faoxis, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+xargs

Comment: Я уж думал, вы в третий раз будете рассказывать про type, ctime и mtime. :)